# Promise.then is not executing in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

JavaScript - Jasmine test framework question

Hi guys, for some reason, helpers.getWeatherData returns a promise but I can't manage to resolve it with the .then

Can't find to much documentation on this either.

Help would be amazing!

```
import Jasmine from 'jasmine'
const jasmine = new Jasmine()
jasmine.loadConfigFile('spec/support/jasmine.json')
import helpers from '../src/lib/helpers'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import Promise from 'bluebird'

describe("Weather Service App", function() {
      const URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?`;

      beforeEach(function(){
          console.log('hello')
          helpers.getWeatherData(URL).then((arr)=>{
          console.log(arr.length, 'length')
        })
      })

      console.log(helpers.getWeatherData(URL))

  it("Test API endpoint, return array of five objects", function() {

  });

});

jasmine.execute()
```

Comment: It is possible that you are getting some exception or error. Add the catch callback and see if you are getting some exception.

Comment: I added a .catch(err) but no error was returned. Thanks tho, I didn't think of that.

Comment: Do you see any request outgoing in fiddler or something?

Comment: request outgoing in fiddler?

Comment: fiddler or any other network monitoring tool should be able to tell you if your request is going out or not, and what is the response(return code at least)

Comment: Oh well the api is working, I'm pretty much using the same code from my test, that helper in my actual application and its working. But in jasmine, its not executing .then so interesting

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the `beforeEach` funciton requires `done` as a parameter when doing things asynchronously.

It would run the beforeEach function without waiting for the promise to fully execute.

To fix, you could try this:

```
  beforeEach(function(done) {
      console.log('hello');
      helpers.getWeatherData(URL).then((arr) => {
        console.log(arr.length, 'length');
        done();
      })
  })
```

See https://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support